# Is it OK to copy Google's AdSense JavaScript code to avoid the mixed content warnings in browsers?

Tags: php, https, adsense

You may know that [Google AdSense doesn't support HTTPS](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=10528).

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588327/avoid-this-page-contains-both-secure-and-non-secure-items-warning) on Stack Overflow about it.

I went to the URL that Google made me include, and copied and pasted the code between `script` tags and it worked.

My question is - is this too flaky, because they might change their JavaScript file at any time?

Or should I request the file with PHP, and then make a local copy of it on my server, which I can access via HTTPS?

Thanks

#### Update

I built a PHP proxy to serve the ads and it works - I'm just going to check if what I'm doing won't annoy Google. :)

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the legal uses of Google's code, Google probably updates their stuff on a fairly regular basis. I would think it would be best to use PHP like you said. If they (Google) offer that as an option, last time I looked though, they only offered the ad scripts in JavaScript, maybe that's changed. That might allow for HTTPS.

Edit: Just looked at the ToS. Found this: "**You will not modify, adapt, translate, prepare derivative works from, decompile, reverse engineer, disassemble or otherwise attempt to derive source code from any Google services**, software, or documentation, or create or attempt to create a substitute or similar service or product through use of or access to the Program or proprietary information related thereto." I think what you're thinking of would require some that. Looks like Google doesn't want you to. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately they don't offer their ads via `https`. The request is aborted because there is not https certificate.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think google will want to compromise the estimated $7.7 billion dollars per second they are generating through Adsense. Knowing google, their thought process may be as follows:

1 - Most people directly link to the source URL. (Revenue = $7.3 billion p/s)

2 - Some people don't. They copy the source and put it between their script tags. (Revenue = $0.4 billion p/s).

```
GoogleBot7: Login Successful. Logged in as Sergey.
GoogleBot7: Determine -now -truth -of -whatiamthinking
/* begin GoogleBot 7 Inference Mastication Profitization Conundrum Decisionism */

GoogleBot7: Thank you GoogleBot 1, we must maintain backward compatibility in
            case lazy site owners have done the copy/paste thingie.
            $0.4 billion p/s is required for Sergey MARS Palace I.

/* end GoogleBot 7 Inference Mastication Profitization Conundrum Decisionism */

GoogleBot7: > Anything else, Sergey?
GoogleBot7: exit
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the technical reasons, which you already outlined (yes, they change their code frequently) you should reread the Adsense agreement. I read it a lot of time ago but I bet that it forbid copying their code.

Answer (score 0):

It would most likely work, until they come out with a new version of their code, but I'm fairly sure this goes against their ToS in some way.